# Stored procedure has too many parameters when being called

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure with parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prAddSortament]
    @Name varchar(255),
    @ProcessingId varchar(35),
    @ShapeId varchar(35),
    @GostId varchar(35),
    @PartOfId varchar(35),
    @DescrArr varchar(max),--varbinary,
    @tsVal varchar(max),
    @SM varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
```

And I'm calling it from my program that way:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MiSConStr))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.prAddSortament", con);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", sort.Name);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProcessingId", sort.Processing.ObjectId);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShapeId", sort.Shap.ObjectId);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GostId", sort.Gost);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartOfId", sort.PartOf);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DescrArr", sort.Description);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsVal", ts);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SM", sortMat);

   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```

On `cmd.ExeccutrNonQuery();` I have an exception

> Procedure or function prAddSortament has too many arguments specified.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641849/procedure-or-function-has-too-many-arguments-specified-but-it-doesnt. You might be executing wrong stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of parameters are same then try to check their types. It looks like there is some mismatch of the data types of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code it will specify the stored procedure you want to add :-

```
cmd.CommandText = "prAddSortament";
```

Extra info for this kind of error as detailed here http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-8144.aspx :-

> SQL Server Error Messages - Msg 8144
>
> Error Message: Server: Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2,  Procedure Stored
>   Procedure or Function Name, Line 0 Procedure or function Stored
>   Procedure or Function Name  has too many arguments specified.
>
> **Causes:**
>
> As the message describes, this error is encountered when you are
>   passing arguments or parameters to a function or stored procedure
>   which is more than what the function or stored procedure is expecting.

```
To illustrate, let’s say you have the following function definition:
> CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_Concat] ( @pString1 VARCHAR(10), @pString2
> VARCHAR(10) ) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) AS BEGIN
>     RETURN ISNULL(@pString1 + ' ', '') + ISNULL(@pString2, '') END
```

> 

```
 This function expects only 2 arguments, namely @pString1 and
> @pString2.  To use this function, you do the following: SELECT
> [dbo].[ufn_Concat] ( [FirstName], [LastName] ) AS [FullName] FROM
> [dbo].[Customers]
```

> 

```
The error will be encountered you pass more than 2 arguments or
> parameters to the function, as follows: SELECT [dbo].[ufn_Concat] (
> [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName] ) AS [FullName] FROM
> [dbo].[Customers]
>
```

> Server: Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Procedure or function
>   dbo.ufn_Concat has too many arguments specified.
>
> **Solution/Workaround:**
>
> To avoid this error from happening, always make sure that you pass the
>   same number of arguments that a stored procedure or function is
>   expecting.  To know the parameters expected by a stored procedure, you
>   can use the sp_help system stored procedure and pass the name of the
>   stored procedure as the parameter.

Comment: I specify it in constructor.

Comment: parameter types must be the same as in the table @Gleb

Comment: what is --varbinary for in ur SP @Gleb??

Answer (score 0):

That was my great fault. I'm using two versions of database, and in the connection string was specified old version of DB, where dbo.prAddSortament exists but have less parameters.